# Server-initiated notifications don't occur on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, live-refresh

Since today, on MSO only (rev 2013.8.23.1375, I get no notification of any kind on Meta Stack Overflow: no live refresh of new answers, comments, questions, not even a red circle in the supercollider to tell me I have a new reply.

It's all working fine on other sites running rev 2013.8.23.967.

Observed in Chrome 28.0.1500.95 and Chrome 29.0.1547.57, both on Linux. I've never had problems with live notifications before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an issue with our site settings load order with respect to data-center specific settings...Marc and I are working on it - it will be resolved ASAP.  You may see them blip on and off here on meta for a bit while we test the fix.

Edit: bug squashed, and a mechanism preventing it gets deployed in the next build.

Comment: Yay! Just saw your two edits live-refresh. Thanks